# How to add previous/next buttons instead of >/< signs in pagination area of category page in opencart without making changes to pagination.php file?

Tags: php, pagination, opencart

I want to add previous/next buttons instead of >/< signs in pagination area of category page in opencart without making changes to pagination.php file.
I want it to be editable using the theme template files, so anyone can download the theme I created, doesn't need to change them using pagination.php file.

Comment: Do you have any code you can show us of things you have tried?  Any references to possible solutions you've tried?  Check out the [Help Center] (https://stackoverflow.com/help) for more details on asking good questions.

Comment: write a module to do that.. that will override the default pagination style